# Battlefield 3 problem connecting to same server on LAN

Tags: battlefield-3, origin, networking

In Battlefield 3, I'm able to connect to a server with a first computer, but the second computer in the LAN will always keep on the "connecting..." phase. I think that happens because I was using the same port.

Origin uses registry to launch the game so I changed the registry to use another port:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\GameUX\Games{438D1154-48C0-41FD-BDB0-BC789AAA5BE3}\AppExePath`

using

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games\Battlefield 3\bf3.exe +clientport 20000`

But it didn't work. Also tried to enable/disable UPnP.

Of course both computers have different accounts.

Comment: You say that origin uses the registry, but the registry entry you list is the windows game interface, not origin. Try making a shortcut on your desktop.

Comment: I often had the same problem with BF2. It did depend on the network I was on though.

Comment: @horatio Origin opens BF via web browser! I can't have access to BF via shortcut because I have to use Origin's web interface. Origin's web interface uses this registry to open the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

had the same problem with a friend, we solved following the howto on [this link on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CoAcRabdxhQ) and also opening the following ports on our router:

- TCP: 80, 443, 9988, 42127
- UDP: 3074, 3659, 6000, 25200

maybe it's helpful for you too (this doesn't work for everybody)